# Observable Collection/ Binding - Resources

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

My current project is parsing some HTML and I want to bind through an Observable Collection.

I have a fairly limited knowledge of C# and I am looking for resources to learn about Observable Collection and Binding.

I have looked at MSDN content for this, but I am after a more real work tutorial or examples if possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx <-- More information on this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should be more specific. Just try and see how far you can come. That said, have you tried this post? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/10/11/datamodel-view-viewmodel-pattern-series.aspx

Comment: @Polity I can't really be more specific. I'm just after soem general info or a tutorial that uses binding and observable collection. Thanks for the MVVM link, I will check that out.